# Does evaluating `true && {}` involve type coercion?

Tags: javascript

Does the following code involve type coercion?

```js
true && {}
```

I ask, because the object instance is being implicitly treated as a different type (a boolean), in order for the operation to succeed. And that appears to meet this definition of coercion [here](https://2ality.com/2019/10/type-coercion.html#what-is-type-coercion%3F):

> Each operation (function, operator, etc.) expects its parameters to
>   have certain types. If a value doesn’t have the right type for a
>   parameter, the two most common options for a caller are:
>
> 1. They can explicitly convert the value so that it has the right type.
>      For example, in the following interaction, we want to multiply two
>      numbers that are written out in strings:
>
> `Number('3') * Number('2') // 6`
>
> 2. They can let the operation make the conversion for them:
>
> `'3' * '2' // 6`
>
> This kind of implicit conversion is called coercion.

Comment: The *evaluation* of the expression involves computing `Boolean({})`, though as you know the result value is just `{}`.

Comment: `1-{}` involves computing `Number({})` (I think), giving (as you know) the result `NaN`.

Comment: No the operands of `&&` are converted to booleans first via the normal "truthiness" algorithm, which is what `Boolean()` does. The spec calls that the `ToBoolean()` internal operation.

Comment: My point is that `1-{}` unarguably involves coercion. And yet that operation appears to follow a similar pattern. The object is coerced via the [`ToNumeric()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumeric) operation.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, I guess it's all down to whether you consider the internal `ToBoolean()` operation performed while evaluating `&&` to be a case of "coercion".  I'd say it is, but I'd also say it doesn't matter to me at all what word one might use do describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no type coercion happening, because the left hand side of your expression is already a boolean value and the right hand side of the AND is just returned.

Type your `true && {}` expression into the console of your browser and you'll see it evaluates to the `Object`. That's because AND returns the right most value as long as all preceeding values evaluate to `true`, while the OR operator "short-circuits": If the left hand side evaluates to `false`, the right hand side is returned.

Other examples are:

```
1 && 'Greets'
[] && Boolean && 'Again'

0 || 'Greets also'
NaN || null || 'Same here'
```

All of these return the last value/the right most value of the expression which, in this example, has a type of `String`.

People often use(d) the behaviour of the OR operator to define "default arguments" for pre-ES2015 code:

```
function incrementBy(value, by) {
  var _by = by || 1;
  return value + _by;
}

incrementBy(1); // -> 2
incrementBy(1, 1); // -> 2
```

If only the first argument is passed, the "default" `1` is used instead of the second argument. However, it contains a subtle bug: If the caller passes the wrong type as a second argument, the result is messed up:

```
incrementBy(1, 'BOOM'); // -> '1BOOM'
```

This can be fixed if both operators are used in conjunction:

```
function incrementBy(value, by) {
  var _by = typeof by === 'number' && !isNaN(by) && by || 1;
  return value + _by;
}
```

The aforementioned bug is now gone:

```
incrementBy(1); // -> 2
incrementBy(1, 1); // -> 2
incrementBy(1, 'Boom'); // -> 2
```

Comment: @BenAston According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) that's not he case. Also have a look at the [description table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description), which explains how the evaluation works.

Comment: @BenAston I get your point. From a strictly technical point of view you are right, the interal algorythm the JS runtime uses indeed does perform a `ToBoolean` coercion when the `&&` is evaluated. However, this does not have any effect on the types at runtime, since the right hand side of `true && {}` evaluates to an `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because `{}` converts into `true`.

Comment: Are you sure? Consider the following for fun: `Boolean({})` - true `true && {}` - {} `true & {}` - 0 `true | {}` - 1

Comment: @enhzflep the `Boolean()` conversion is performed *internally* during the evaluation of the `&&` expression.  Also, the `&` and `|` operators have completely different semantics.